# Moving Text Over a Picture

Tags: html, css

I want to move the title text over the picture.  Changing the picture's bottom margin to -50% helped, but the text would move significantly depending on the size of the screen.

```css
.banner{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: none;
    bottom margin: none;
}

.title h1{
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: black;
    float:left;
}

.title p{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Joe's Garage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Garage CSS">
    </head>
    <body> 
         <div class="banner">
             <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562837d1e4b0c53c5afbc078/t/5863246febbd1ab7ab5125b6/1482892406200/slide_405344_5057908_free.jpg?format=1500w">
         </div>
         <div class="title">
             <h1>JOE'S GARAGE</h1>
             <p>We Take the Worry Out of Car Trouble by Delivering Accurate Repairs at an Honest Price</p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the title in the middle of the image? You could do this very easily with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Yes I do!  I tried it just now, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely use a `background-image` for this. This is what it's for, after all.

```
.banner {
    background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562837d1e4b0c53c5afbc078/t/5863246febbd1ab7ab5125b6/1482892406200/slide_405344_5057908_free.jpg?format=1500w');
    background-size: cover; // or 'contain', depending on what you want.
}
```

For best results, put the overlaying markup inside the `.banner` container, add some `height` control, `background-position` styles, and your favorite vertical-alignment trick (assuming you want the text centered vertically as well as horizontally).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    align-items: center;
    background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562837d1e4b0c53c5afbc078/t/5863246febbd1ab7ab5125b6/1482892406200/slide_405344_5057908_free.jpg?format=1500w') center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.title h1, .title p {
    color: red;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>JOE'S GARAGE</h1>
    <p>We Take the Worry Out of Car Trouble by Delivering Accurate Repairs at an Honest Price</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I initially had it as a background image, but I didn't know how to show more than the div's height and keep it centered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the text over the image in a div, I have the solution :)

You can have some flex guide (it's very nice for css).

> Flex guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Method:** I have used the `.banner div` as container for the `.title and .text`.

The `.banner .content` define the `margin` (if you want to put the title, ... in the bottom/left...)

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.banner {
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562837d1e4b0c53c5afbc078/t/5863246febbd1ab7ab5125b6/1482892406200/slide_405344_5057908_free.jpg?format=1500w) no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover !important;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.banner .content {
  margin:5px 0 0 0;
  /** or margin auto if you want to centered the content, margin auto 0 0 0 if you want to align on the bottom...**/
}

.banner .title {
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:1.5em;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
}

.banner .title, .banner .text {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">My title</div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.banner{
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: none;
    bottom margin: none;
}

.title h1{
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: black;
    float:left;
}

.title p{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Joe's Garage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Garage CSS">
    </head>
    <body> 
         <div class="banner">
             <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562837d1e4b0c53c5afbc078/t/5863246febbd1ab7ab5125b6/1482892406200/slide_405344_5057908_free.jpg?format=1500w">
         </div>
         <div class="title">
             <h1>JOE'S GARAGE</h1>
             <p>We Take the Worry Out of Car Trouble by Delivering Accurate Repairs at an Honest Price</p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can add position: absolute; to place the text over the image.

```
.banner{
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: none;
    bottom margin: none;
}
```